# Docbook xi:include

Tags: xml, xml-validation, docbook

I am trying to create a docbook. I have created a main XML book and inside it I am using `<xi:include>` to add different chapters.

I am following [DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide / Using XInclude](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ModularDoc.html#UsingXinclude) to create book and chapter files.

Here is my main XML file `book1.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
                      "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<book>
  <title>MAIN NOTES</title>
  <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="CH1.xml" />
</book>
```

And here is my chapter1 (`CH1.xml`).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE chapter PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
                         "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<chapter id="CH1">
  <title>Chapter 1</title>
  <para>This is Test</para>
</chapter>
```

Now when I am validating these XML files, `CH1.xml` is ok. But I am always getting

> No Declaration found for element "xi:include"

for `book1.xml`. What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: Which parser do you use? Is it XInclude-aware, or can you check that XInclude features are enabled?

Comment: I use xsltproc with option --xinclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make DTD validation work when using XInclude is described in another section of "DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide": http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ValidXinclude.html.

In short, there are two alternatives:

1. Validate after XInclude processing. With xmllint, this can be done using this command:
   `xmllint --xinclude --postvalid book1.xml`
2. Customize the DTD to include the `xi:include` element.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem. I used `xmllint --xinclude --postvalid book1.xml` and output is a valid xml.